# How to jump to the location which [I points to?

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-javascript, include

I've installed node plugin, which give possibility to display all lines that contain the keyword under the cursor using `[I` hotkey. It looks like this:
[image]

Is there possibility to jump to them?

Comment: The line numbers are there so you could type `114gg` too jump to the second entry. Though I guess that only works if its your current buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is built-in, it has nothing to do with that "node" plugin. It's called "include search" and you can read all about it in `:help include-search`.

You have a few ways to jump to an item in the list:

- `:136<CR>` will jump to line 136 but *it is obviously restricted to the current buffer* and you only jump to the line, not the match,
- `:ijump 3 <C-r><C-w>` will jump to the third item in the list, across buffers,
- going back to normal mode and doing `3[<C-i>` has the same effect as above.

But those methods aren't particularly easy on the fingers.

You can create a simple custom mapping to make it a lot smoother:

```
nnoremap [I [I:ijump  <C-r><C-w><S-Left><Left>
```

Here is a simplistic demo:

[image: silly demo]

There's also [this gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/romainl/3c7ee68125f822ec550c) that overrides the native `[I` (among others) to use the much more powerful quickfix list/window:

[image: Ilist()]

Comment: For your third option, it may help that `<C-i>` is the same as `<Tab>` in most terminal emulators.